# Position independent executable and fixed entry point address

Tags: gcc, position-independent-code

A position independent ELF executable can be loaded and run from arbitrary address within the virtual address space.

I tried to build below simple program:

**pie.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("hello, pie!\n");
}
```

Build command:

```
gcc pie.c -o pie -pie
```

The ELF header of the executable is:

**pie**:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x530 <================= FIXED entry point
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6440 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
```

So the entry point address is fixed.

And it is the symbol `_start` there:

```
0000000000000530 T _start
```

So it means the `_start` must be placed at `0x530`.

**Isn't this contradictory to being position independent?**

### ADD 1 - 10:44 AM 8/16/2021

I tried to build the same program without the `-pie` flag:

```
gcc pie.c -o pie_not
```

The generated ELF header is:

**pie_not**:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x530  <============ Still the same value as with -pie flag
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6440 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
```

And I further compared the built results `pie` and `pie_not`. Their binaries are identical.

**So how could the operating system tell which one should be treated as position independent code??**

### ADD 2 - 10:56 AM 8/16/2021

I guess I figured it out.
It seems gcc use `-pie` by default. To avoid it, I have to add `-no-pie` flag explicitly.

```
gcc pie.c -o pie_not -no-pie
```

And the generated ELF header is like this:

**pie_not**:

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file) <==== File type also changed!!!
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400400 <===== Entry point address changed!
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          6376 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         9
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 28
```

I believe the loader relies on the Type filed in ELF header to decide how to treat the binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a position-independent executable, the entry point address in the ELF header isn't used as the absolute address of the entry point.  Rather, it's used as an offset from the randomly chosen base address.

So in your example, if the base address is randomly chosen as `0x567812340000`, then execution will start at absolute address `0x567812340530`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to know the load address of the program at runtime? I guess I should check the `/proc` file system but I am still looking into it.

Comment: You could tweak your linker script to add a symbol at relative address 0, which you can then reference like any C variable.  Or, at least on my system, there's one already defined called `_init` at address 0x1000.  So `extern char _init[]; printf("Base address is %p\n", _init - 0x1000);`